# Feedback on setting up a "Programmer Dojo" -- suggestions?

Tags: planning, culture, meetings

Looking for a case study, or operational plan for setting up a "programmer/hacker dojo" in the United States. Here's an example of one, [**hackerdojo.com**](http://hackerdojo.com); it's possible this info is on their site, but I have been unable to find it.

---

**UPDATE (1):**

- **Wikipedia** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_Dojo
- **WSJ** - [Techies Get to Work at Hacker Dojo](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703386704576186530946790912.html)  (2011/03/10)
- **venturebeat** - [Hacker Dojo, finally a hangout where coders can go 24/7](http://venturebeat.com/2009/08/13/hacker-dojo-finally-a-hangout-where-coders-can-go-247/) (2009/08/13)

---

**UPDATE (2):**

- [Learning Space Matrix - Microsoft Corporation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCMQFjAC&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/1/8/4182DF40-7EA3-4C13-91D0-E3B75D639590/LearningSpaceMatrix.doc&rct=j&q=Community%20Centric%20Working%20Space&ei=c4iaTYTkA5SO0QGxmYzdBg&usg=AFQjCNH3wM7kIP6WDPmO5KNNF_cqLcKxCg&cad=rja) (MS Word Doc, [Google Preview](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aYAajUsC9EbkJ%3adownload.microsoft.com/download/4/1/8/4182DF40-7EA3-4C13-91D0-E3B75D639590/LearningSpaceMatrix.doc%20Community%20Centric%20Working%20Space&))
- **KEYWORDS:** Community Centric Working Space

Comment: @closer: If the question is off-topic, just explain why, and I'll delete the question. Cheers!

Comment: Is this like a punk rock house with more compuers? Because the punk rock house was fun in the right context . . .

Comment: @Wyatt Barnett: Yeah, I think it'd be a crazy amount of fun... main thing I want is a solid legal framework... since the last thing I need is a police raid, or anything like that.

Comment: I guess I'll be moving to California, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the best place to start would be contacting the creators of the Hacker Dojo and of several popular hackerspaces/makerspaces and ask for their advice on what worked and what didn't work.

Hackerspaces have become extremely popular over the past couple of years, and I know of several that have done very well.  I'm good friends with several of the members of Huntsville's [Makers Local 256](https://256.makerslocal.org) and I know that they would be glad to help others by sharing ideas and practices that worked well for getting things off the ground.

I don't see a programmer/hacker dojo being too much different from a hackerspace, so contacting any group that has made something work would most likely benefit you.

Comment: +1 @sp0rus: I did, no lucky getting any info of use directly from them; called and emailed. Their responses via email  told me to come in, or look at the site; guessing I just reached the wrong person, since I'm sure there's someone there that'd be happy to chat with me about it. I'll follow up with 256 to see what suggestions they have in the next few days. Selecting your reply as the answer, since it is on topic, of use, and the question has been open for awhile. Cheers!

Comment: @blunders Sorry I couldn't provide a hard answer to your question, but I figured I'd give you something since no one else seemed to want to answer.  We've considered starting a hackerspace here, and the advice most established groups gave us off the bat was "Do it. It's like Field of Dreams: if you build it, they will come."  Another group to look ask might be Blooming Labs http://www.bloominglabs.org/index.php/Main_Page